# Inconsistent package.xml - Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, xml, marketplace, package

I tried finding a Slack or Discord server for Magento before coming here.

I am trying to submit a Magento 1 extension for technical review @ marketplace and the `package.xml` won't pass marketplace validation. I manually fixed specific fields that failed, but the error is now `Repo rejected file upload - Failed.`

The error is a bit abstract, but I'm pretty sure it's related to the `package.xml`. I regenerated it for post-1.5 releases via **Magento Connect** (running on Magento 1.9.4.1), but the generated XML is quite different than the previous one, and I can't seem to find anything useful in official docs.

The previous XML had a calculated hash for each file under `contents`, the current one has only one hash.

Can someone explain the difference(s) between https://github.com/sendwithus/extension-magento/blob/master/dist/package.xml and https://github.com/meanbee/magento-diymage/blob/master/package.xml?